# How do you prove inequalities like $x^2 + xy + y^2 \ge 0$?

Tags: inequality

This is what I am asking. I do not want you to prove these inequalities for me; instead, I would like you to teach me a general method with which I can prove the inequality:

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 \ge 0$$

If you could prove a similar inequality to illustrate the general method, I will be thankful.

Comment: If $xy$ is non-negative, your first inequality follows from $x^2+y^2\ge0\ge -xy;$ if $xy$ is negative $(x+y)^2\ge0\implies x^2+y^2\ge-2xy\ge -xy$

Comment: Or $x^2+xy+y^2=\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\geq0.$

Answer (score 4):

This is  a *homogeneous* polynomial in $x$ and $y$. So set, e.g., $y=tx$, and rewrite it as
$$x^2+xy+y^2=x^2(1+t+t^2)$$
So all you have to prove is that $1+t+t^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y$, then $x^2+xy+y^2=3x^2\ge 0$.

If $x>y$. Then:
$$x^3> y^3 \iff x^3-y^3> 0 \iff (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)> 0 \iff x^2+xy+y^2> 0.$$

Can you check the case $x<y$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first inequality is $$x^2+2x\frac{y}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}+y^2-\frac{y^2}{4}\geq 0$$ (completing the square)
For the second inequality
$$x$$ is not a solution ,then we can write
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-3(x+\frac{1}{x})+4=0$$ then Substitute
$$t=x+\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGrauber so applying completing the square as I would apply it to quadratics; like in high school algebra? can it be proved directly, ie direct proof. by applying completing the square and factoring I obtain a true statement and from this true statement I obtain the original inequality. Is this how you prove it?

Comment: @JobH: In general, you rewrite inequality in such way that you can use one of the proven inequalities like $x^2 \ge 0, e^x >0$, AM-GM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x,y$ to be real,

$x^2+xy+y^2=\dfrac{(x+2y)^2+3y^2}4$

If $z/x^2=(x+1/x)^2-3(x+1/x)+4-2=(x+1/x-1)(x+1/x-2)$

Now $x+1/x\ge2$ or $\le-2$

Answer (score 1):

Any $x^2+cxy+y^2$ with $-2\le c\le 2$ is a convex combination of $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2\ge 0$ and $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2\ge 0$, hence non-negative.

Comment: Obviously you mean $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x\color{red}+y)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

- If $xy \geq 0$, then there is nothing to prove.
- If $xy <0 \Rightarrow$:
  $$x^2+xy+y^2 = x^2-|x||y|+y^2 > x^2-2|x||y|+y^2 = (|x|-|y|)^2 \geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Show $x^2+xy+y^2 \ge 0$.

1) If $x,y\ge 0:$

$x^2,y^2, xy \ge 0$, the sum is  $\ge 0$√.

2) If $x,y \le 0:$

$x^2,y^2, xy \ge 0$, as before the sum $\ge 0$√.

3) Let $xy \le 0$.

Assume $x \lt 0$, $y \ge 0$.

Consider $m:=\max(|x|, y).$

$x^2+y^2+xy = x^2+y^2-|x|y \ge$

$ x^2+y^2-m^2 \ge 0$ (Why?).

Assume $y \lt 0$, $x \ge 0$, and complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since

   > $$\begin{equation}\begin{split} y^{2}+ yx+ x^{2}= (- y+ x)^{2}+ 3yx= (y+ x)^{2}- yx \end{split}\end{equation}$$
2. Since

   > $$\begin{equation}\begin{split} y^{2}+ yx+ x^{2}= \frac{y^{3}- x^{3}}{y- x}\geqq 0\because \lim_{y\rightarrow x+ 0^{+}}\frac{y^{3}- x^{3}}{y- x}= 3x^{2}\geqq 0, \lim_{y\rightarrow x+ 0^{-}}\frac{y^{3}- x^{3}}{y- x}= 3x^{2}\geqq 0 \end{split}\end{equation}$$